# ActiveAdmin invoke after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin class, where i have written create action for some changes, because of which after_save doesn't get called on "create", but it works fine on "update". Is there any way to register callback on create manually???

Thanks.

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyClassName do
 def create 
 end
 after_save do |myclassname|
  #This doesn't get called on create
  #Works fine on update
 end
end
```

Comment: what happens if remove that definition for create and try creating ?

Comment: Can you call super at the end of your create method?

Comment: If i remove create definition it works fine. Nope, i can't call super, doing a lot of things in create